# Tensor products, classic proof question

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Reviewing the proof that $\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$, and remembered that Dummit and Foote makes this statement on p. 369:

"Observe that $a \otimes b = a \otimes (b \cdot 1) = (ab) \otimes 1 = ab(1 \otimes 1)$."

I'm probably missing something straightforward here, but I thought you could only pass across the $\otimes$ with *ring* elements, not module  elements. Since *b* is an element of integers mod n$\mathbb{Z}$, not the integers, how come I'm allowed to bring the *b* across here?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is a ring

Comment: Right, so I see that I can pass elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ back and forth, but $b \in \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It may have been clearer to use the notation $[a]_m \otimes [b]_n = ab([1]_m \otimes [1]_n)$, but the author is letting $a$ and $b$ be representatives of equivalence classes as well as the classes themselves.

Comment: Perhaps there is a very standard 'abuse of notation.' (Temporarily) write $b$ for an element of the integers, and $\overline b$ as the (corresponding) element of the module ${\mathbb Z} / n{\mathbb Z}$. Then $\overline{ b} = b \overline {1}$. Oops, same comment as @kobe.

Comment: This just now dawned on me as well. Thanks! I don't think I'd paid close attention to this abuse of notation before.